# Application Insights REST API doesn't return rows

Tags: azure, rest, azure-application-insights

I use [this endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/query/execute?tabs=HTTP) to query data from my App insight
The problem is, it always returns empty rows i.e. `"rows": []`.

```
{
  "tables": [
    {
      "name": "PrimaryResult",
      "columns": [
        {
          "name": "timestamp",
          "type": "datetime"
        },
        {
          "name": "message",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "severityLevel",
          "type": "int"
        },
        ...
        {
          "name": "_ResourceId",
          "type": "string"
        }
      ],
      "rows": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to check if I am missing something. I use Nightingale for it, here are my values:

```
Method - POST
URL - https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/query
BODY - {
    "query": "traces | where timestamp <= ago(120m) | limit 10"
}
HEADERS - {"X-Api-Key": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}
```

I tried changing my query, adding timespan, using GET, tried adding "Content-Type" or "charset" to headers. I also tried querying using OAuth 2.0 but still get response 200 but empty results. Here are some screenshots on how do it using OAuth
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why it works for others but not for me. My Application Insights resource is **workspace-based** and this fact seeming prevents you from reading data straight from app insights. I tried creating one using "standalone" setup and it works.

So, in order to query data from workspace-based app insights, I need to send queries to the related workspace and then, inside the query, specify the actual app insights I need, like this:

```
METHOD - POST
URL - https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/workspace_id/query
AUTH - OAuth 2.0
BODY - {
  "query": "app('app001_test').traces",
  "timespan": "PT24H"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I deployed one Function App with Application Insights and queried the traces parameters like below:-

Instead of less than equal to I used greater than equal to and it gave results, Refer below:-

```
traces | where timestamp <= ago(120m) | limit 10
```

[image]

[image]

```
traces | where timestamp >= ago(120m) | limit 10
```

Output:-

[image]

I called a Rest API to get these rows, like below:-

```http
GET 
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:<client-id>
client_secret:<client-secret>
scope:https://api.applicationinsights.io/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

Got access token like below:-

[image]

Used this access token to call the Application Insights API like below:-

```http
POST https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/xxxxxxxx-b7c0-43d0-83a7-552exxxxxx/query
```

[image]

Pass below parameter in the Request Body make sure you add timespan with query.

```json
{

"timespan": "P1D",

"query": "traces | where timestamp >= ago(120m) | limit 10"

}
```

[image]

After sending the POST request got rows of the table in the output:-

[image]

Comment: I thank you for the amount of work you've done. For some reason or another it still doesn't work for me no matter what I do

Comment: Does it return any table and rows in the Application Insights > Logs > And when you query traces? Also, Can you try using client credentials flow like the answer?

Comment: Yes, it does return it if you use GUI. After messing with it yesterday I can say with confidence that something is missing from my app like permissions etc. I managed to query data from another app insights but not from mine.

Comment: Check if you have this Application Insights API Permissions granted to your app, Also, your app should have Contributor role assigned to the application Insights resource and the app resource- https://i.imgur.com/46G6Hvg.png

Comment: It was because mine was workspace based and not standalone. I post an answer to my question.